# How to register iOS application as virtual printer like android printService

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, airprint, android-print-framework

I have developed an android application which implements a printer service like provided by Google in this link :

- [**PrintService Documentation**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrintService.html)

this helps me to register my android application as a printer , so when the user is interested in printing a document from any other android application, My application will be listed as a printer and it can handle the print request and it works as expected .

Now I'm working on an iOS version of the application .So I want to know if there is an equivalent iOS Service or PrintJob that I can implement in my application in order to register it as a  virtual printer or **Air Printer**  .

Comment: did you ever find out if this is possible?